# Make available site through http after deploy onto Netlify

Tags: http, netlify

I am using two application parts that deployed on: AWS Beanstalk and Netlify.

Java-based part is deployed on AWS and available on http protocol.
Angular based is deployed on Netlify and available on https protocol.

The error occurs when sending a request to AWS:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://some-url.netlify.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://some-url.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/getAppSettings'. This request has
>   been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I need to do it working for learning purposes only, so try to make Netlify working under Http.

Is it possible to change the protocol to simple http on Netlify?

The adding SSL certificate to Elastic Beanstalk is complicated, unclear and takes too much time

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, netlify doesn't allow you to access website over HTTP, as they force redirect to HTTPS by default, as mentioned [here](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/07/02/all-new-sites-on-netlify-are-https-by-default/). But its really easy to have HTTPS on AWS - your elastic beanstalk instances are served with HTTPS by default using an AWS owner certificate, and you can link your custom domain certificate if you have a custom domain, very easily from AWS Certificate Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a netlify.toml file and do some redirect tweaking, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/158#issuecomment-540140129).

Answer (score 0):

Creating and configuring a _redirects file in the root of your build folder(or in your public folder if using an SPA like React) might help with this. For your example, the _redirects file would look something like this:

```
/api/* http://some-url.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/:splat 200
```

Then rather than call endpoints like this:

```
fetch(`http://some-url.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/getAppSettings`)
```

You would need to make your API calls in this format:

```
fetch(`/api/getAppSettings`) // 'it reads /api/ because of how we configured our _redirects file'
```

You can read more on how to make netlify proxying [here](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#proxy-to-another-service)